# Is there a difference between using 1d conv layers and 2d conv layers with kernel with size of 1 along other than time dimension?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, prediction, time-series, convolution, forecasting

Let's assume I use convolutional networks for time-series prediction. Data I feed to the network have 1 channel depth, height of number of periods and number of features is the width, so the frame size is: 
[1, periods, features]. Batch size is not relevant here.

Is there a difference between using 1d convolutions along time (height) dimension and 2d convolutional that will have a kernel size of for example (3, 1) or (5, 1), so that the larger number convolutes along the time dimension, and there is no convolution along features dimension?